# Serving webp images conditionally if the browser supports it in IIS

Tags: wordpress, iis, url-rewriting, webp

Serving webp images instead of jpeg and png if the browser supports it seems to be possible when using .htacess files and apache.

I have never managed to get this to work with IIS. I usually use WordPress as my CMS of choice, and there are WordPress plugins with automatic webp conversion of existing uploaded images and redirection included, but the redirection/conditional detection don't work with IIS out of the box.

I have already made all necessary preparations like allowing the webp extension and MIME in IIS. Loading an existing webp file is not a problem, I just don't want to load the webp version when using inferior browsers like IE11 and Safari, as it will not display anything. There are tons of guides on the internet explaining how to enable webp support in IIS, but I have managed to find 0 articles how to actually use it in a real life scenario where the website has to display properly in IE11 and Safari.

Comment: You first need to view the error message through the F12 developer tools, and then solve the problem based on this error message.

Comment: You did not provide enough information about the naming. How are your WEBP files named when compared to PNG and JPG versions? `a.jpg` -> `a.jpg.webp` or `a.jpg` -> `a.webp` and vice versa? This is crucial to be able to write the rules. If your current `.htaccess` contains the related rules, it would be good to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect `webp`-urls to fallback `jpeg`-urls.

According to [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) it can be done with a rule similar to

```xml
<rules>
    <rule name="Some name" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)\.webp$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="*MSIE*" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}.jpeg" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

---

<sup>I don't have nor IIS, nor IE, so I can't test it.

Also if your fallback images have different extensions it's up to you to come up with a way how to decide which of `webp` images map to `jpeg` urls and which map to `png`. Or you could choose to redirect the other way around - `jpeg/png`-urls to `webp`-urls.</sup>